# Persistent Storage with Docker Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume, data-persistence

How can I ensure data persistence when using Docker volumes for a database container? Are there specific strategies or configurations to ensure the data isn't lost when containers are recreated?

---

**Title:** Difficulty Achieving Persistent Storage Using Docker Volumes for Database Container

**Body:**

I'm currently working on setting up a Dockerized environment for my application, and I'm encountering challenges with achieving persistent storage for my database container using Docker volumes.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Created a Docker volume and mounted it to the database container using the `-v` or `--mount` option.
2. Verified that the volume was correctly attached to the container and that data was being written inside the container.
3. Stopped and removed the container to test if the data remained intact within the volume.

**Expectations:**

I anticipated that the data stored within the Docker volume would persist even after stopping or removing the container. However, upon recreating the container, the data seems to be lost, indicating an issue with the volume setup.

**Specific Questions:**

1. Are there additional configurations or settings needed to ensure that the data within the Docker volume remains persistent across container restarts?
2. What best practices should I consider to maintain data integrity when using Docker volumes for persistent storage with database containers?

I'm seeking advice or suggestions on how to properly set up Docker volumes to ensure consistent and persistent data storage for my database container. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Some sort of volume or bind mount is probably the right answer, but without knowing what you're mounting or where it's a little hard to tell what might be going wrong.